# How to make banner image zoom out to show more of the image?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using an image as a banner of a page that is showing about half of what i'd like it to. I am attempting to have the banner image zoom out if possible without adjusting the size of the actual banner container itself. I've tried adding a height css property but it is increasing the size of the banner container. Is there a way to show more of the image with a css property?

Here is my [current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGLR9.png) cut off example.

Here is what i'd like to show entirely [desired example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz53Q.png)

html code:

```
<div class="page-banner-container ca-state"> 
        <div class="banner-content">
                 California               
        </div>
    </div>
```

css for banner image:

```
.page-banner-container.ca-state {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(90, 90, 97, 0.7), rgba(90, 90, 97, 0.7)), url(/banner-ca.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

page banner container css

```
position: relative;

width: 100%;

height: auto;

min-height: 280px;
```

Comment: background-size: 100% auto;

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
img{
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:-1;
 }

.page-banner-container.ca-state {
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 
<div class="page-banner-container ca-state"> 
        <div class="banner-content">
                 California               
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="img">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz53Q.png" alt="">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Its still much like OP's first image

Comment: you mean it has opacity?

Comment: The background 100% doesn't appear to look any different from the `background-size: cover` that i'm using. Adding height to the container adjusted the height of the div rather then zoom out the image. which im trying to avoid, is there anyway to zoom out of it rather then adjust height?

Comment: do you mean something like this?